# What is the rule behind the way singleton dimensions are squeezed in a submatrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

It appears to me that MATLAB squeezes the singleton dimensions on the right-hand side of the last non-singleton dimension, with the restriction that a matrix must be at least two dimensional.

Inferring a rule from examples makes me feel uncomfortable, but it seems to work.

in 2D:

```
E = zeros(2,3);

E(1,:); % 1x3
E(:,1); % 2x1
```

in 3D:

```
E = zeros(2,3,4);

E(1,:,:); % 1x3x4
E(:,1,:); % 2x1x4
E(:,:,1); % 2x3

E(1,1,:); % 1x1x4
E(:,1,1); % 2x1
E(1,:,1); % 1x3
```

in 4D:

```
E = zeros(2,3,4,5);

E(:,:,:,1) % 2x3x4
E(:,:,1,1) % 2x3
E(:,1,1,1) % 2x1

E(1,:,:,:) % 1x3x4x5
E(1,1,:,:) % 1x1x4x5
E(1,1,1,:) % 1x1x1x5

E(:,:,1,:) % 2x3x1x5
E(:,1,:,:) % 2x1x4x5

E(1,:,:,1) % 1x3x4
E(1,:,1,:) % 1x3x1x5
E(:,1,:,1) % 2x1x4

E(1,1,:,1) % 1x1x4
E(1,:,1,1) % 1x3
```

Can anyone confirm whether this is the rule?

Incidental question: does this rule also apply to functions such as `diff()`? It seems like so.

The only difference I see is that you can get an empty matrix,then singleton dimensions on the left-hand side of the empty dimension are not removed, even when it is the greatest dimension:

```
E = zeros(2,3,4);

diff(E,1,1) % 1x3x4
diff(E,3,2) % 0x3x4

diff(E,2,2) % 2x1x4
diff(E,3,2) % 2x0x4

diff(E,3,3) % 2x3
diff(E,4,3) % 2x3x0
```

in 4D

```
E = zeros(2,3,1,5);
diff(E,3,4) % 2x3x1x2
diff(E,4,4) % 2x3
diff(E,5,4) % 2x3x1x0
```

Then again, this is just an ad hoc explanation and I am not going to test every possible case. What is the rule?

Comment: But then try this: `E = zeros(2,3); size(E,3)`! Each array actually has an infinite number of singleton dimensions at the end!

Comment: Interesting comment. It makes me think of trailing zeros in the decimal part of a floating point number, with the difference that leading singleton dimensions are preserved whereas leading zeros in the integer part are not significant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any trailing singleton dimensions higher than the second are automatically stripped off. So `1x2x1` will automatically become `1x2`, as will `1x2x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1`, but `2x1` remains `2x1`. This happens when you index, like in your question, but also when a function like `diff()` would output something ending in singleton dimensions.

Any singleton dimensions **not** being the last are left. Thus `1x2x1x1x1x2` remains `1x2x1x1x1x2`, and `1x2x1x1x1x2x1x1` becomes `1x2x1x1x1x2` as well. You can force the [`squeeze()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to force all singleton dimensions out; you'll always be left with at least a 2D matrix though (even if it is just a `1x1` scalar).

---

As a sidenote, as [Cris Lunego](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723014/what-is-the-rule-behind-the-way-singleton-dimensions-are-squeezed-in-a-submatrix/56723069#comment100010063_56723014) said,

> But then try this: `E = zeros(2,3); size(E,3)!` Each array actually has an infinite number of singleton dimensions at the end!

So technically each array has an infinite number of dimensions, with the last ones all being empty, and MATLAB not showing them by default, but they are indexable:

```matlab
A = rand(3,3);
A(2,2,1)
ans =
    0.4854
A(2,2,1,1)
ans =
    0.4854

size(A)
ans =
     3     3
size(A,4)
ans =
     1
```